# How to make toolbar in tinymce-react keyboard accessible?

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, tinymce, focus, accessibility

I am using tinymce-react latest version i.e. 3.8.4.. It's toolbar is not keyboard accessible. I cannot access any of toolbar buttons (Undo,Redo,Bold,Underline,italic etc) using Tab or Alt+F9.  How can I make it accessible?

Comment: Are you sure, I mean I have never tested it from an accessibility perspective but I know if your press Alt + F10 it does at least allow some keyboard navigation. Alt + F9 to hit the file menu btw. Other than that this question is far too broad, we would have to explain the entirety of accessibility standards to help, so voting to close the question. If you have a more specific problem click the "Edit" link (next to "Share") and provide some more details.

Comment: please share what you have done and how/where it is not accessible

Comment: Do these jsfiddle attempt to do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cyrossignol/e5c3wbbr/  http://jsfiddle.net/GwkRQ/357/

Comment: Is this the latest version of the tinymce that you want to use?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS yes this one is the version that I want to use.. Also in the example that you shared`(https://jsfiddle.net/cyrossignol/e5c3wbbr/)`, when I press Tab it takes me to the stackoverflow hyperlink at the bottom (skips tinymce toolbar).Also Alt+F9, Alt+F10 doesn't work.  How can I focus toolbar with undo,redo and other formatting icons

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Graham Ritchie - your question is pretty vague around what you are after and could use more details.  That being said, the TinyMCE docs do have a page dedicated to all the keyboard shortcuts available and how you can navigate around the editor via the keyboard:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/keyboard-shortcuts/#accessibilitykeyboardshortcuts

***Note:**  I work for the company and owns TinyMCE and we are used by some very large corporations that require the editor is accessible to users via the keyboard so I am confident we are fundamentally accessible with regard to keyboard navigation/operation.*

Comment: In this tinymce-react storybook example [link](https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-react/?path=/story/tinymce-react--disable-button), If I enable tinymce using enable button on top. And try to access toolbar, the sequence of focus is as follows

1) Disable button is focused
2)Text Area of the Editor is focused(the toolbars are skipped)
Also I am not able to access toolbar using Alt+F9(as written in documentation)